# How to replace title tags with QTIP

Tags: jquery, qtip

Consider me a complete newbie! I just want title tags replace with QTIP.
I've installed qtip and jquery on my server, I just don't know how to replace title tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tip/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tip/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Does something go here?
</script>
```

Comment: let's see your html structure for the things you want the tips on.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample below is from here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#replace

```
$('a[title]').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true } })
```

That line of code will replace all the 'title' attributes of HTML anchors with the qTip tool-tips.

So inside your script block where you wrote 'Does something go here?', you would want to wrap the above line within a jquery 'ready' function:

```
$(function () {
    // the qTip code above goes here, in order to call on document-load
}
```